# Migrating from exsheets to xsim

Tags: exsheets, xsim

`xsim` looks fine.

EDIT, March 28, 2019

I know, the manual has to be read! But just one question: How to mimick in `xsim` this `exsheets` setup?

```
\SetupExSheets{%
    counter-format = ch.qu,
    counter-within=chapter,
    label-format = ch.qu:#1,
    headings-format={\color{blue}\sffamily\scshape\bfseries}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED, March 28, 2019

Ok, this solved my requirement, declare a template:

```
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{blue} {%    
    \par
    \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}     
    \noindent
    \textsf{\textcolor{blue}{\scshape{\bfseries{\GetExerciseName}%   
    \nobreakspace\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}}}%
    \quad } 
{\par\bigskip}
```

And use it:

```
\xsimsetup{%     
    exercise/within = chapter ,      
    exercise/template = blue  ,  
    exercise/the-counter = \thechapter.\arabic{exercise} 
}
```

Just as I pointed before, it's in the manual!!